# Way to silent output and provide clear fail or success of command

Tags: unix, terminal, stdout, error-code

I am looking to run a command `jest` and have it not log anything, as well as use the exit code and give a clear success / fail one-line message. How is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You could redirect the output to `/dev/null` and ignore the STDERR by doing something like this:

```
command1 > /dev/null 2>&1 && command2
```

You can test with `ls`, for example:

```
ls non-existent > /dev/null 2>&1 && echo "success"
```

If won't print anything (if file `non-existent` doesn't exist), and exit code will be > 0, you can check the status code by running after executing the command: `echo $?`

To test when exit code is zero, try:

```
ls -al > /dev/null 2>&1 && echo "success"
```

It will print "success"

The `&&` will execute `command2` if (and only if) `command1` returns exit status zero.